# PHP array_merge() with preference of first array and unique values only?

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I would like to merge multiple arrays together while taking preference of the values from the first array and only having unique values. Is there a quicker way than using `array_merge()`, `array_unique()`, and the `+` operator?

```php
function foo(...$params) {
    $a = [
        'col1',
        'col2_alias' => 'col2',
        'col3'
    ];
    $merged = array_merge($a, ...$params);
    $unique = array_unique($merged);
    print_r($merged);
    print_r($unique);
    print_r($a + $unique);
}

foo(
    ['col4', 'col5_alias' => 'col5', 'col6'], 
    ['col7', 'col1', 'col5_alias' => 'col5', 'col2_alias' => 'col10']);
```

Just merging the arrays gives me duplicate values, and overwrites values in the first array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => col1 // duplicate
    [col2_alias] => col10 // overwritten
    [1] => col3
    [2] => col4
    [col5_alias] => col5
    [3] => col6
    [4] => col7
    [5] => col1 // duplicate
)
```

Using `array_unique()` obviously fixes the duplicate values, but not the overwritten value:

```
Array
(
    [0] => col1
    [col2_alias] => col10
    [1] => col3
    [2] => col4
    [col5_alias] => col5
    [3] => col6
    [4] => col7
)
```

After using the `+` operator, the array is how I want it.

```
Array
(
    [0] => col1
    [col2_alias] => col2
    [1] => col3
    [2] => col4
    [col5_alias] => col5
    [3] => col6
    [4] => col7
)
```

Comment: Would you consider using a collection library?

Comment: What is bad in + operator if it works fine? Is it slow?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGuimarães Unfortunately, it's in legacy code, and adding a collection library would be a hassle.

Comment: @instead I haven't tested how slow/fast this is, but I can't imagine using 3 array functions would be faster than using 1 or 2.

Comment: Can't think in a solution other than mapping the merged keys and doing it inside the closure. I prefer using the union operator (+).

Comment: if the array union operator (`+`) works fine, just use it and move onto more important things. Note though, that it doesn't prevent duplicate values if there are duplicates already in an array or between the two arrays. If you want to have a custom merge, just make your own function that does what you want. If you think the issue is performance, you are likely talking about microseconds of optimizations.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn Just want to make sure I was clear in that the union operator by itself does not work, because it keeps the indexes (so 'col4' would be overwritten). I must use the union operator with merge and unique. I figured having to use all three together would slow things down, but that's an assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right to assume that using the `array_merge`, `array_unique` functions, and `+` operator would be slow. And I've written a bit of code to benchmark the speed of each combination...

Here is that code...

```
<?php

class ArraySpeeds
{
    public $la = ['col1', 'col2_alias' => 'col2', 'col3'];
    public $a = ['col4', 'col5_alias' => 'col5', 'col6'];
    public $b = ['col7', 'col1', 'col5_alias' => 'col5', 'col2_alias' => 'col10'];
    public $c = [];

    public function executionTime ($callback)
    {
        $start = microtime (true);

        for ($i = 0; $i < 1000000; $i++) {
            $callback ();
        }

        return round ((microtime (true) - $start) * 1000) . '/ms' . PHP_EOL;
    }

    public function getTimes ()
    {
        $array_merge_time = $this->executionTime (function () {
            $this->c[0] = array_merge ($this->la, $this->a, $this->b);
        });

        $array_unique_time = $this->executionTime (function () {
            $merged = array_merge ($this->la, $this->a, $this->b);
            $this->c[1] = array_unique ($merged);
        });

        $addition_time = $this->executionTime (function () {
            $merged = array_merge ($this->la, $this->a, $this->b);
            $unique = array_unique ($merged);
            $this->c[2] = $this->la + $unique;
        });

        $array_diff_time = $this->executionTime (function () {
            $merged = array_merge ($this->a, $this->b);
            $diffed = array_diff ($merged, $this->la);

            $this->c[3] = array_merge ($diffed, $this->la);
        });

        echo print_r ($this->c[0], true), PHP_EOL;
        echo print_r ($this->c[1], true), PHP_EOL;
        echo print_r ($this->c[2], true), PHP_EOL;

        natsort ($this->c[3]);
        echo print_r ($this->c[3], true), PHP_EOL;

        echo 'array_merge: ', $array_merge_time;
        echo 'array_unique: ', $array_unique_time;
        echo 'addition: ', $addition_time;
        echo 'array_diff: ', $array_diff_time;
    }
}

$arrayspeeds = new ArraySpeeds ();
$arrayspeeds->getTimes ();
```

This is the output...

```
Array
(
    [0] => col1
    [col2_alias] => col10
    [1] => col3
    [2] => col4
    [col5_alias] => col5
    [3] => col6
    [4] => col7
    [5] => col1
)

Array
(
    [0] => col1
    [col2_alias] => col10
    [1] => col3
    [2] => col4
    [col5_alias] => col5
    [3] => col6
    [4] => col7
)

Array
(
    [0] => col1
    [col2_alias] => col2
    [1] => col3
    [2] => col4
    [col5_alias] => col5
    [3] => col6
    [4] => col7
)

Array
(
    [3] => col1
    [col2_alias] => col2
    [4] => col3
    [0] => col4
    [col5_alias] => col5
    [1] => col6
    [2] => col7
)

array_merge: 403/ms
array_unique: 1039/ms
addition: 1267/ms
array_diff: 993/ms
```

You can see the execution time gets longer with each added function call, with the `array_merge`, `array_unique` functions and `+` operator being the slowest, more than twice as slow.

However, using `array_diff` will get you a decent performance with the correct output, but without correct sorting. Adding a `natsort` function call to the array would fix that.

For example...

```
function foo (...$params)
{
    $a = [
        'col1',
        'col2_alias' => 'col2',
        'col3'
    ];

    $diff = array_diff (array_merge (...$params), $a);
    $merged = array_merge ($diff, $a);
    natsort ($merged);
    print_r ($merged);
}
```

Comment: I don't need them to be sorted, so this works perfect, thank you!

Comment: I voted up this answer, but for some reason it still shows zero. If you didn't get the rep points, let SO know.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I do not see any major issues with your script and I do not know why you want to improve it. But I've written my implementation of your function and it seems that it works a little faster, have a look (I've also added a few more params to test function results):

```
<?php

function foo(...$params) {
    $a = [
        'col1',
        'col2_alias' => 'col2',
        'col3'
    ];
    $merged = array_merge($a, ...$params);
    $unique = array_unique($merged);

    return $a + $unique;
}

function foo2(...$params) {
    $a = [
        'col1',
        'col2_alias' => 'col2',
        'col3'
    ];
    $merged = array_merge(array_diff(array_merge(...$params), $a), $a);

    return $merged;
}

$timeFoo = microtime(true);
for($i = 0; $i < 1000000; $i++) {
    foo(
    ['col13', 'col5_alias' => 'col3', 'col8'],
    ['col21', 'col5_alias' => 'col1', 'col9'],
    ['col4', 'col5_alias' => 'col5', 'col6'], 
    ['col7', 'col1', 'col5_alias' => 'col5', 'col2_alias' => 'col10']);
}
$timeFoo = microtime(true) - $timeFoo;


$timeFoo2 = microtime(true);
for($i = 0; $i < 1000000; $i++) {
    foo2(
    ['col13', 'col5_alias' => 'col3', 'col8'],
    ['col21', 'col5_alias' => 'col1', 'col9'],
    ['col4', 'col5_alias' => 'col5', 'col6'], 
    ['col7', 'col1', 'col5_alias' => 'col5', 'col2_alias' => 'col10']);
}
$timeFoo2 = microtime(true) - $timeFoo2;

echo "'foo' time: $timeFoo \n";
echo "'foo2' time: $timeFoo2 \n";
```

Results differ from time to time, but not so much:

```
'foo' time: 3.4310319423676
'foo2' time: 2.5314350128174
```

So it gives us nearly 30% performance boost.